# How do you adjust column width of a table

Tags: tables, columns, width

I have a table in the following code:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \footnotesize
  \caption{\label{tab:dimensionlessnumber}
  Definitions and physical meanings of dimensionless quantities.}
  \begin{ruledtabular}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
  \textrm{number group} & \textrm{Definition} & \textrm{Physical meaning}  \\
  \colrule
  Density ratio               & $D=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}$
  & A measure of the ratio of the A to B densities            \\
  Reactive number             & $R=\frac{s\Delta p}{a b C}$
  & The ratio of two very different quantities, a measure of the rate of reaction (very complicated), different from another definition in the reference                         \\
  Non-dimensional non-trivial parameter & $N=bk/aC$
  & A measure of the non-trivial degree at another side       \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

In this table,

1. The 2nd row of the 3rd column cannot be shown completely. Is there any way to
   automatically split the long entry in multi-lines with an appropriate column width so that text wider than the column width will be put on a new line?
2. The 3rd row of the 1st column was obviously longer than the length of others.
   I have tried `\\` to break it on a new line. But in this way,
   the entry of the second column, e.g., the definition of `$N$`, will then follow the second row, see the next figure. Instead, I want it in the first row.

To solve the problem, I have used `tabularx` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`, as shown in the [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249049/text-in-table-cell-not-wrapped-after-using-fix-width/249057#249057) and [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250021/fix-column-width-of-table/250025#250025). I even used `\footnotesize` to reduce the font of the table. But the problems remain. Thanks for any suggestion!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove `ruledtabular` and use `p` type for the first column. Also to make the table a bit more readable, you can increase line spacing by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`. Finally, instead of multiple `\hline`s, you may consider using `booktabs` for much better output.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \caption{\label{tab:dimensionlessnumber}
  Definitions and physical meanings of dimensionless quantities.}
  %\begin{ruledtabular}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\raggedright}p{10em} l X }
  \hline \hline
  \textrm{number group} & \textrm{Definition} & \textrm{Physical meaning}  \\
  \hline
  Density ratio               & $D=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}$
  & A measure of the ratio of the A to B densities            \\
  Reactive number             & $R=\frac{s\Delta p}{a b C}$
  & The ratio of two very different quantities, a measure of the rate of reaction (very complicated), different from another definition in the reference                         \\
  Non-dimensional non-trivial parameter & $N=bk/aC$
  & A measure of the non-trivial degree at another side       \\ \hline\hline
  \end{tabularx}
  %\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AboAmmar for your answer! Do you mean it is the using of `ruledtabular` or `\hline` that made the `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` and `X`invalid? Actually, I have been following the style of APS template, which recommends `ruledtabular` and `\hline`.

Answer (score 1):

a variation of nice [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar) answer:

- more space between table rows is obtained by use of `\makegapedcells` macro from package `makecell`
- top and bottom horizontal lines are replaced with `Xhline{0.8pt}`
- equations are in `\displaystale`

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\makegapedcells
    \caption{Definitions and physical meanings of dimensionless quantities.}
\label{tab:dimensionlessnumber}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\raggedright}p{10em}
                            >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}
                            X }
\Xhline{0.8pt}
number group    &   \text{Definition}   &   Physical meaning    \\
\hline
Density ratio   & D=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}
    &   A measure of the ratio of the A to B densities          \\
Reactive number & R=\frac{s\Delta p}{a b C}
    &   The ratio of two very different quantities, a measure of the rate of reaction (very complicated), different from another definition in the reference                                               \\
Non-dimensional non-trivial parameter
                & N=\frac{bk}{aC}
    &   A measure of the non-trivial degree at another side     \\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find that the best solution is given here:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_change_column_or_row_separation_in_LaTeX_tables%3F

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
```

They increase the column width and row width respectively. Enjoy!

Comment: `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}`  does not increase the usable width of a column but increases the small horizontal white space to either side of a column's text.

Comment: You probably also wanted to write "column width and row height"  instead of " column and row width".

Comment: That is very opinion based and depends on table content ...

Comment: Yes, it puts white-space. I am not sure what else one is looking for here. Anyway, `\makecell{}` can be handy otherwise.